# Insert values in table from front-end CategoryId

Tags: sql-server, table, c#

I want to add a value from front end into a table. I want to do it in asp.net. I have a table which is as below:-

```
CategoryId     int          
CategoryName   nvarchar(50)   not null
ParentId       int            null
```

Also see the code:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnCategoryUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Category" Width="110" />
```

I tried with my code like this:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="110" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

Code behind for the same:-

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CategoriesForMerchant values (@CategoryName, @ParentId)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", txtCategory.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", "");
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('File uploaded successfully');</script>");
}
```

But I got the below error, please help.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "fk_subcategories". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Test", table "dbo.CategoriesForMerchant", column 'CategoryId'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Please help

Table code:-

```
 create table [dbo].[categories](
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    name nvarchar(50) not null,
    parent int null,
 constraint [pk_categories] primary key clustered ( id asc))

go

alter table [dbo].[categories]  with check add  constraint [fk_subcategories] foreign key(parent)
references [dbo].[categories] ([id])
go

alter table [dbo].[categories] check constraint [fk_subcategories]
go
```

Comment: what you want, on which column the foreign key is applied?

Comment: What is the Foreign Key definition?

Comment: TestDB.dbo.CategoriesForMerchant: fk_subcategories. Please see URL for your ref: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=14141623675613

Comment: @MarkSinkinson: See the edited question for your ref:

Comment: table name i have changed in my actual DB

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to insert a value into `parent` that is not already an `id` within `dbo.categories`. You cannot do that. The `id` referenced by the `parent` value has to exist in the table.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson: I have to give user a way to add category and sub category from the front end. If this way is not possible, can you help me in making the other way out so that I can give user a way to add from the front end

Comment: Surely `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", "");` is not required? If you send an empty value, SQL Server will not treat it as a NULL. Either submit a value in it, or delete that line of code.

Comment: Ok, will remove that from the code. What else has to be done. Please mention. I am going on a client call. Sorry for that. Pls do let me know what else steps I have to take.

Comment: Hi @MarkSinkinson: Waiting for your reply..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18756/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-mark-sinkinson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Button Click, I got to do something like this, as suggested by @MarkSinkinson.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CategoriesForMerchant (CategoryName) values (@CategoryName)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", txtCategory.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('File uploaded successfully');</script>");
}
```